# Exclude post from query_posts() wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude a post from loop like:

```
query_posts("posts_per_page=5&cat=1, -15&post__not_in = 1");
```

However, `post__not_in` isn't working. Do I have the command all wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because `post__not_in` expects an array which you can use when you are using the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

Try using `WP_Query` instead:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,
              'cat'            => '1,-15',
              'post__not_in'   => array(1),
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($posts->have_posts()) {
    $posts->the_post();
    echo the_title() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Odd thing is, it's now only showing that post, even though there is the - sign.

Comment: I checked and negatives aren't supported for the post ID in the case of `query_posts`, see updated example which works properly.